# Cocoa Bindings and Checking for String content

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift, binding

OK, here's what I want to do :

- Let's say I have an item, e.g. an `NSTextField`
- Let's also say we want to bind its `hidden` value to a `BOOL` variable - that's easy.

Now, here's the twist :

- I want to bind the `hidden` property to a check in the fashion of (`someStringVariable == "Some String"`)
- In a few words : set the element to hidden when `someStringVariable` is equal to some string.

How can I do that from within the IB? Is it doable?

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is basically a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26419637/bindings-and-conditionally-set-hidden) which I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26420405/1312143). But somebody other than the questioner has put a bounty on this one, so:

Entirely within IB? No.

You can bind to a string-typed property and then use a custom value transformer to convert that string to a boolean according to its equality to the desired value.

However, it's probably just easier to add a property to the class that has the string-typed property:

```
// Assumed to exist:
@property (copy) NSString* someStringProperty;

+ (NSSet*) keyPathsForValuesAffectingShouldBeHidden
{
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"someStringProperty"];
}
- (BOOL) shouldBeHidden
{
    return [self.someStringProperty isEqualToString:@"desired string"];
}
```

Since this property is really part of the UI rather than the model, you may wish to define it in a category on the model class. The category itself would be declared and defined in the controller code.

Once it's defined, you can bind to the `shouldBeHidden` property.

Comment: I think, this should be the the accepted answer. One other approach would be to use KVO.

Answer (score 0):

You mean someting like this?

```
string1=string2 ? hidden=true : hidden=false
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: well I thougth that was what he wanted... Any way I'm sorry, I'm new here, thanks for the explanation @Igor