# Bindings and conditionally set hidden

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, binding

I have an `NSArrayController` bound to an `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableDictionary`s.

**Something like that :**

```
[
    { "label" : "label1", "type" : "string" },
    { "label" : "label2", "type" : "boolean" }
]
```

Now, this array controller is in turn bound to an `NSCollectionView`, where each row (`NSCollectionViewItem`) represents a row in the initial array.

And I can obviously get a value like: `representedObject.label`, `representedObject.type` and so on.

**Now here's the tricky part:**

If I want to create a binding for the `hidden` property of a - let's say - `NSTextField`, based on the type (sth like "if type==string setHidden:YES else setHidden:NO", in plain english), how is that doable with bindings? Should I try Value Transformers?

---

**P.S.**

- *The scheme with the bindings and everything so far works great, and I wouldn't like to - all of a sudden - start creating a mess out of it.
  So, any advice is more than welcome!*
- *The question has been tagged with [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) as well (although I'm interested in OSX), since there shouldn't be any great difference + OSX-only questions are sadly more likely to be ignored.*

Answer (score 2):

I find that using `NSMutableDictionary` for model objects is OK for quick-and-dirty prototyping but that, in a real app, you pretty quickly get to a point where you're better off creating a proper model class.  Modern Objective-C makes this really easy:

```
@interface Thing : NSObject

@property (copy) NSString* label;
@property (copy) NSString* type;

@end

@implementation Thing
@end
```

and that's it.  Now, you want the "stringTyped" property, or something like that.  You add:

```
@property (readonly) BOOL stringTyped;
```

to the interface and:

```
+ (NSSet*) keyPathsForValuesAffectingStringTyped
{
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"type"];
}
- (BOOL) stringTyped
{
    return [self.type isEqualToString:@"string"];
}
```

to the implementation.  (You don't actually need to add the property to the interface for bindings to find it.)

The `+keyPathsForValuesAffectingStringTyped` method allows KVO to know what, when the `type` property is changed, it should also emit change notifications to observers of the `stringTyped` property, if there are any.  See `+[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserving) keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:]` to see why this works.

If the `stringTyped` property doesn't really make sense in your model, you can actually add that property via a category that's defined in your controller layer.  Basically, your controller knows the model and it knows the view needs a way to translate from the `type` property to the a hidden attribute.  So, it can add that translation layer.  In this case, you might rename the property to `hidden` since it's OK to have it reflect how the view will use it.

You definitely can accomplish this with a value transformer.  However, you would ideally want value transformers to be general purpose and not specialized to a single view's needs.  But that's not a hard-and-fast rule.

> **P.S.**
>
> - *The question has been tagged with [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) as well (although I'm interested in OSX), since there shouldn't be any great difference +
>     OSX-only questions are sadly more likely to be ignored.*

Don't do that.  Bindings is not available on iOS, so there is a "great difference".

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's how I ended up doing it... (Btw, I really did not know Bindings were OSX-only. wow.)